# React Native + Jest - FlatList error - "ReactDebugCurrentFrame.setExtraStackFrame is not a function"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to test a simple React Native (Expo Managed) FlatList-based component using Jest. Jest is set up using the `"preset": "jest-expo"` setting.

The code for the component looks as follows:

```
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { Message } from "../../../graph/graph";
import MessageComponent from "../message";

export interface MessageStackProps {
  messages: Message[];
}

export default function MessageStack({ messages }: MessageStackProps) {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const message = item as Message;
    return (
      <MessageComponent
        text={message.text}
        targetStatuses={[]}
        sentDate={new Date()}
      />
    );
  };

  return <FlatList data={messages} renderItem={renderItem} />;
}
```

My test is as follows:

```
function render(messages: Partial<Message>[] = []) {
    return render(<MessageStack messages={messages as Message[]} />);
  }

it("should render a single message for one message", () => {
    const message: Partial<Message> = {
      id: 1,
      text: "Test message",
    };
    const { getAllByText } = render([message]);

    expect(getAllByText(/message/i)).toBeArrayOfSize(1);
  });
```

I receive the following error when running this test:

```
TypeError: ReactDebugCurrentFrame.setExtraStackFrame is not a function
The above error occurred in the <CellRenderer> component:
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a known issue?

I would appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess in the wild: Could you please try to add a `key` prop to MessageComponent?

```js
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const message = item as Message;
    return (
      <MessageComponent
        key={message.id}
        text={message.text}
        targetStatuses={[]}
        sentDate={new Date()}
      />
    );
  };
```